# Add click handler to LI bullet

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'd like to add a JQuery click handler specifically to the bullet on an LI. Currently, when I click on any of the elements WITHIN the LI, the LI click handler fires. Instead, it should only be the bullet and not any of the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll need to make your own bullet then, possibly as a DIV with a background image.

Comment: not really, but you just define an inline-block styled div class of specific dimensions and background image and then listen for the div class click event.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep the native bullet you could do this:

HTML:

```
<li><span>Text here</span></li>
```

JS:

```
$('li').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName != 'LI') return;

    alert('clicked bullet');
});
```

Comment: Works so long as there are not nested lists. :)