# Is it possible to setup a click event for the number of an ordered list item?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html-lists, onclicklistener

In an HTML document, is it possible to setup a click event for only the number of a list-item (`li`) or bullet in an ordered list (`ol`)?

I'd like to be able to click on the number and then do some processing. So far I've had two thoughts but was hoping there was some other way to do it with a normal ordered list:

1. Use CSS counters to inject numbers into an element that I would place where the number would have been.
2. Absolute position a transparent element over the number from inside the associated list item.

Below is a sample of the list. I want to be able to click on the part that shows up as `1.`, `2.`, or `3.`.

**HTML source:**

```
<ol>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
</ol>
```

**Result in browser:**

```
1. First Item
2. Second Item
3. Third Item
```

Comment: You can assign events only to HTML/DOM elements, and a number in front of a list item is a part of that element. So, your idea #2 might be the only way to achieve this. #3 would be to assign a handler to the whole list, and check the click-point...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081774/add-click-handler-to-li-bullet

Comment: What browser? In Chrome this works perfectly see http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/6nxeT/

Comment: @HBP, I wanted the click to only fire when clicking on the number, not the entire `li`. I suppose I could wrap everything inside the `li` and catch/ignore the click event, but was hoping there was simply a way to access the numbers for the list items but it doesn't sound like that's possible according to Teemu. Right now I'm leaning towards option #2.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, I'll edit it to make it clearer. @Fellexe has the right solution for you then. I have updated my fiddle to do what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying @Fallexe suggestion but adding the spans in JS:

```
[].slice.call (document.querySelectorAll ('ol, ul')).forEach (function (list) {
    for (var s, el = list.firstElementChild; el; el = el.nextElementSibling)
      el.innerHTML = '<span>' + el.innerHTML + '</span>';

    list.addEventListener ('click', function (ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName !== 'SPAN')
          for (var el = this.firstElementChild; el; el = el.nextElementSibling)
              el.className = el === ev.target ? 'selected' : '';
    }, false);    
});
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/6nxeT/

Comment: I made a slight modification to the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ScrM5/ to fill the entire area of the list items.

Comment: Great that's what it's all about.

Answer (score 1):

Use this class, and just play with with z-index, you can make it.

```
.all {
    margin-left:-30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

for RTL direction:

```
.all {
    margin-right:-30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

i.e : http://jsfiddle.net/ESQKV/